# Gadgets drains battery in backgournd while not even used nor allowed?

Tags: 8.1, battery, nokia-lumia-930

I have a Lumia 930 WP8.1 and I keep seeing the Gadgets app with 20+% usage in battery saver (last 24h) and I noticed my battery draining quicker in the past week.

I do own 2 DT-903 charging pads, one at work and one at home, but I don't have Bluetooth enabled on my phone and I've disabled background work for Gadgets app. About a week ago I did enable Bluetooth to fiddle around with pairing the chargers and whatnot, but I've disabled it a long time ago.

I thought maybe because I charge with the plate, it perhaps counts it as background work. To test this, I only used the regular cable charger yesterday, unplugged in the evening (around 6-8 pm) and without using the phone at all, in the morning I woke up with 60% battery.

I restarted the phone (hold power and volume down) and turned it off and on, but the gadgets still stays at the top of battery usage.

What else can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Last two weeks my Lumia 920 started to get empty in a few hours without using it; I remarked the Phone was frequently rather warm. When I researched the consumption it seamed that the app "Gadgets" consumes continuously in the background. Rebooting my Phone did not help, so I removed the app "Gadgets" and now the problem is solved.

Answer (score 4):

Do You have other devices on your network? If so, it's connected to your phone and if You have a lot of devices connected to That network it'll automaticly connect (or trying to connect). Try deleting These devices. Then restart your phone and done. If it didn't work, There'll be a software/phone issue.